# Storing Same Record my on Submit Button

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hello I'm looking to get the record and save it to my data base but all the time I'm getting the same sql statement for all the select options

```
Course ID INSERT INTO `tbl_assign_course` (`course_id_1`, course_id_2`, `course_id_3`) VALUES ('7', '7', '7')
```

[Here is the Options list to choose:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfmuO.png)

How I can fix this logical error I will appreciate any kind of help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> The University</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
    <?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>
</div>
<?php
print_r($result);
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo(base_url() . "University/std_course_assign/" . $result[0]['course_id'] . "/" . $result[0]['course_i'] . "/" . $result[0]['course_id']); ?>">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name='course_id_1'>
                    <option value="">--- Select Course ---</option>
                    <?php
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) { ?>
                        <?php echo "<option value=" . $result[$i]['course_id'] . ">" . $result[$i]['course_name'] . "</option>"; ?>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name='course_id_2'>
                    <option value="">--- Select Course ---</option>
                    <?php
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) { ?>
                        <?php echo "<option value=" . $result[$i]['course_id'] . ">" . $result[$i]['course_name'] . "</option>"; ?>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name='course_id_3'>
                    <option value="">--- Select Course ---</option>
                    <?php
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) { ?>
                        <?php echo "<option value=" . $result[$i]['course_id'] . ">" . $result[$i]['course_name'] . "</option>"; ?>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="std_id" value="<?= $std_id ?>">
                    <input type="Submit">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Model Function

```
public function std_course_assign($course_id) {
    $data = array('std_id' => $this->input->post('std_id'),
                  'course_id_1' => $this->input->post('course_id'),
                  'course_id_2' => $this->input->post('course_id'),
                  'course_id_3' => $this->input->post('course_id'),
        );
    $this->db->insert('tbl_assign_course', $data);
    $this->db->where('std_id', $this->input->post('std_id'));
    print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: you are using same query result `$result[$i]`, i think so

Comment: post your INSERT query

Comment: public function std_course_assign($course_id)
{
 $data= array(
 'std_id'=>$this->input->post('std_id'), 
 'course_id_1'=>$this->input->post('course_id') ,
 'course_id_2'=>$this->input->post('course_id'),
 'course_id_3'=>$this->input->post('course_id'),
  );
 $this->db->insert('tbl_assign_course', $data); 
 $this->db->where('std_id',$this->input->post('std_id'));

 print_r($data);
}

Comment: why you are using `where` in `INSERT` code ?

Comment: If you insist on assigning everything the same value, they will be... the same value. You might want to read over your code one more time...

Answer (score 1):

Your insert query is wrong, change it to 'course_id' to 'course_id_1' 'course_id_2' and so on:

```
public function std_course_assign($course_id) { 
    $data= array( 
        'std_id'=>$this->input->post('std_id'), 
        'course_id_1'=>$this->input->post('course_id_1'), 
        'course_id_2'=>$this->input->post('course_id_2'), 
        'course_id_3'=>$this->input->post('course_id_3')
    ); 
    $this->db->insert('tbl_assign_course', $data); 
    $this->db->where('std_id',$this->input->post('std_id')); 
    print_r($data); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anand Pandey it's working. Just missed to read the code.

Comment: Glad to help :) please accept the answer if you like

Answer (score 0):

I think You are using `WHERE` condition with `INSERT` query, use correct `INSERT` query for *desired result*.

and use correct `attribute name` in insert query